# classcast exception in using BaseExpandableListAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, classcastexception

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams is the error

i am using a BaseExpandableListAdapter as follows. where instead of passing a list, i am directly passing a View to be a child data. and the child count is always returned as 1. as there is only one view per heading.

```
public class TaxAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

    private Context _context;
    private ArrayList<String> _listDataHeader; 
    private HashMap<String, View> _listDataChild;


    public TaxAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> taxListDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, View> taxListDataChild) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = taxListDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = taxListDataChild;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
         return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
         return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition));
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
         return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LinearLayout earningsContainer = new LinearLayout(_context);
            LayoutInflater inflator = ((Activity)_context).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row_tax_explv_title,
                    earningsContainer, false);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.explvTaxTitleText)).setText(headerTitle);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        return (View)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

and the data being passed from the activity is as follows -

```
    ArrayList<String> TaxListDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    HashMap<String, View> TaxListDataChild = new HashMap<String, View>();

TaxListDataHeader.add("Movie Shows");
TaxListDataChild.put("Movie Shows", moviesContainerView);
TaxListDataHeader.add("Theatre Shows");
TaxListDataHeader.add("Theatre Shows", theatreContainerView);
```

movieContainerView and theareContainerView are the two custom inflated linear layouts.like this

```
LayoutInflater inflator = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row_movie_data,
                movieMainContainer, false);

        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtEmpInfoPopUpTitle)).setText(key);
        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtEmpInfoPopUpValue)).setText(value);
        return row;
```

i am getting the error as in the title, but the logs do not specify any file name as such.
Please suggest where the error might be occuring. Please suggest what can be done.

**EDIT:**
This is the stack trace

```
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074): Process: com.synthesize.paysal, PID: 5074
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java:1183)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1149)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1226)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:326)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-17 22:53:57.043: E/AndroidRuntime(5074):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT:**
i have tried to wrap the linear layout with a list view like this,

> TaxListDataChild.put("Theatre Show", (new
>   ListView(context)).addView(theatrerowContainer,
>   LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

but it seems that the second parameter is void.

I am populating the "new Linearlayout" (earningsContainer) in the xml like this with other linear layout rows.

```
for (int i = 0; i < taxMainObject.getTaxEarnings().size(); i++) {
        earningsContainer.addView(getTaxEarningsRow(taxMainObject
                    .getTaxEarnings().get(i)));
            totalEarnings += taxMainObject.getTaxEarnings().get(i)
                    .getTotalAmount();
        }
        earningsContainer.addView(getTaxTotalRow("GROSS TOTAL SALARY",
                totalEarnings + ""));
```

and the xml for the rows is -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#ffeeeeee" >


   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTotalText"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:textAppearance="@android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#736F6E"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="2dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTotalValue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#736F6E"
             android:gravity="right"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet but try where you are casting to android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams and change it to casting to android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams (don't ask me why they needed more than 1 layout params class), however if this in an internal android file you might have to find the method that does the casting and overwrite it with your own